# MAC OS X php sql_serv driver how can i install?

Tags: php, macos, driver

I want to connect to a remote database from localhost. I can do this from a windows computer. But I can not do it from an operating system with mac os operating system. I downloaded and run a driver file based on my php version on Windows. But how can I do this in the mac os operating system? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

According to the official PHP documentation, [SQLSRV requires Windows](http://php.net/manual/en/sqlsrv.requirements.php):

> The SQLSRV extension can be used on the following operating systems:
>
> - Windows Vista Service Pack 2 or later
> - Windows Server 2008 Service Pack 2 or later
> - Windows Server 2008 R2
> - Windows 7
>
> The SQLSRV extension requires that the Microsoft SQL Server 2012 Native Client be installed on the same computer that is running PHP.

However some users have [managed to install it on macOS](https://github.com/Microsoft/msphpsql/issues/198) by following the [instructions provided by Microsoft](https://github.com/Microsoft/msphpsql/tree/dev#install-unix). Assuming you have already installed PHP from Homebrew, the installation boils down to something like

```
brew tap microsoft/msodbcsql https://github.com/Microsoft/homebrew-mssql-release
brew update
brew install --no-sandbox msodbcsql
brew install mssql-tools
brew install autoconf
```

and then

```
chmod -R ug+w /usr/local/opt/php71/lib/php
pear config-set php_ini /usr/local/etc/php/7.1/php.ini system
```

I encourage you to read the GitHub issue and the related documentation in their entirety.